# Flickr API batch download

Tags: flickr

I was wondering if it's possible to use the Flickr API to get a batch of images (by doing a REST call and defining multiple tags), and providing a download button for the end user which allows him to download a zip file of the photos? I can get a list of all the image urls in JSON format, but not a whole batch.

I can't seem to find it in the Flickr documentation but was hoping someone could give me confirmation.

Thanks!